# Button Background color of grid view is not changing according to condition

Tags: android, gridview

I want to change the color of buttons in my Grid view according to a value changed . My code is here. But it is not working . Always gets same color for all buttons

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            System.out.println("Inside GETVIEW()");

            if (convertView == null) {
                 System.out.println("Inside convertVIEW()");
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_toggle_button, null);
                holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.each_device);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                View_device.add(convertView);
               if (Constants.Score!=null) {
                Log.i("SCORE:ARAY LIST",""+Constants.Score);

                for(int m=0;m<Constants.Score.size();m++)
                {
                    if(Constants.Score.get(m)==0){
                        holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_btn);//FAILED
                        Log.i("SCORE::ZERO","RED BACKGROUND");
                    }
                    else {
                        holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_btn);//PASS
                        Log.i("SCORE::ONE","GREEN BACKGROUND");
                    }
                }
               }
              }}
```

Comment: `can show the layout and screenshot how its currently looking`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the *for* loop as below, it will work.

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    System.out.println("Inside GETVIEW()");

    if (convertView == null) {
         System.out.println("Inside convertVIEW()");
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_toggle_button, null);
        holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.each_device);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        View_device.add(convertView);
       if (Constants.Score!=null) {
        Log.i("SCORE:ARAY LIST",""+Constants.Score);


            if(Constants.Score.get(position)==0){
                holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_btn);//FAILED
                Log.i("SCORE::ZERO","RED BACKGROUND");
            }
            else {
                holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_btn);//PASS
                Log.i("SCORE::ONE","GREEN BACKGROUND");
            }

       }
      }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            System.out.println("Inside GETVIEW()");

            if (convertView == null) {
                 System.out.println("Inside convertVIEW()");
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_toggle_button, null);
                holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.each_device);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
                View_device.add(convertView);
           }else{
               holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
               if (Constants.Score!=null) {
                Log.i("SCORE:ARAY LIST",""+Constants.Score);

                for(int m=0;m<Constants.Score.size();m++)
                {
                    if(Constants.Score.get(m)==0){
                        holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_btn);//FAILED
                        Log.i("SCORE::ZERO","RED BACKGROUND");
                    }
                    else {
                        holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_btn);//PASS
                        Log.i("SCORE::ONE","GREEN BACKGROUND");
                    }
                }
              }else{
                holder.button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_btn);//FAILED
                            Log.i("SCORE::ZERO","RED BACKGROUND");
    }
 }
```